# If I buy an SSD now, and then new computer parts later, will I have to reinstall the OS?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, computer-building

I just ordered a new computer (CPU, GPU, RAM, ...), but it won't arrive for another week. I also want to buy an SSD though. If I buy it now, and install Windows 7 on it, will I have to reinstall it when I get my new parts so that it recognizes and installs the drivers for them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows installs pretty quick on a SSD. Just learn some patience and wait a week, then set everything up. You wont save any time by installing today if you have to spend a bunch of time finding drivers and fixing everything that is broken when you put the drive in the new PC.

Comment: True... even if I don't have to reinstall the OS, I'd have to reinstall the drivers. Bummer :P I'm just too excited for my new PC :D